# Trying to POST only after an AJAX request but the POST keeps firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to post after each completed ajax request ..

```
     jQuery(function($) {
        jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {data:'hello'}, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        });
    });
```

This just keeps firing and won't stop. If I do an alert it only fires twice since there are two requests but the POST for some reason just keeps firing.

Comment: `$.post` makes an ajax request

Comment: You should hook your `.post()` call into the completion of only the specific ajax calls you want it to fire for by using the `complete: fn` argument to those specific ajax calls.  Then you won't get this infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the docs:

> Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is
>   an AjaxEvent.

obviously an event is being fired once the post request is done putting you in an endless loop.

You can use some thing like

```
$.get(....).complete(function(){
 $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {data:'hello'}, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
   });
})
```

In case you want it to happen when ever an ajax request takes place you will have to add the event listener to each request and remove it in each `$.post`

Comment: That makes sense! I don't know why that didn't hit me as to why I was in a loop.